# Special Characters in MySQL Table Name

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'e!' (
`aa` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`showName` TEXT NOT NULL default '',
`startDateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL default '',
`endDateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY  (`aa`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then tried to insert with the query:

```
INSERT INTO e! (showname, startDateTime, endDateTime) VALUES('E! News ', '2012-05-03 19:00:00', '2012-05-03 20:00:00')
```

And it errors due to the `!` in the table name, I'm assuming `!` is a special character in mysql.  I tried to escape it but the query still failed.

So, can I have special characters like `!` or `&` in the table name? If yes, then I probably have to encode them somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Quote your ambiguous or "special" table names with a back tick:

```
INSERT INTO `e!` ...
```

Or better, don't use special characters in table names to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 13):

According to the docs, you can't:

> Identifiers are converted to Unicode internally. They may contain
>   these characters:
>
> - Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>     ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
>     Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
> - Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:
>     ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
>     Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `e!` (
`aa` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`showName` TEXT NOT NULL default '',
`startDateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`endDateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY  (`aa`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have whatever special requirements for the table identifiers, that means there is something wrong with your database architecture and/or with understanding database architecture.

You'd better correct these architectural mistakes instead of enforcing silly identifiers

Comment: I definitely agree it's better not to use odd identifiers in the table names, I know I could easily map the specials to another valid string.

Comment: LOL @peasant13337 you didn't get the point. there should be no *need* in them, no matter disguised or not. you just don't understand the purpose of these identifiers

Answer (score 0):

You need back-ticks around the e!

Also, your `datetime`s need default values that resolve to a `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:**
>
> ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar,
>   underscore)
>
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
>
> **Permitted characters in quoted identifiers** include the full Unicode
>   Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:
>
> ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
>
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
>
> ASCII NUL (U+0000) and supplementary characters (U+10000 and higher)
>   are not permitted in quoted or unquoted identifiers.
>
> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist
>   solely of digits.
>
> Database, table, and column names cannot end with space characters.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score -1):

This is [Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)
standards for MySQL. According it you can't use "!" symbol as part of table name.

Comment: ["Any character is legal in database or table identifiers except ASCII NUL (X'00')"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-mapping.html)