# How to select a column with a # in its name in R?

Tags: sql, r

```
 loannumber<-sqlQuery(ch,"SELECT LOAN# FROM srvdsrl1")
```

This is an ODBC table and field name is LOAN#

This is the error

```
[1] "42S22 1054 [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.22]Unknown column 'LOAN' in 'field list'"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT LOAN# FROM srvdsrl1'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more a database issue than R. In case of MySQL (as can be deducted from the error description) columns with special characters should be quoted: `'LOAN#'`. See [Special Characters in MySQL Table Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443050/special-characters-in-mysql-table-name)