# Request MS SQL table with diaeresis in name from PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

We need to retrieve data from a MS SQL server from a client with a diaeresis in the table name (which is bad practice). 
The table name is `BE België$Cities` and we are not allowed to change the table name. The request `SELECT * FROM [BE België$Cities]` returns a table not found error.

How can we retrieve data from this table?
We are using SQL Server 2008, PHP7 and Laravel 5.3.

Comment: have you tried with back tick in table name ?? visit this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10443100/4952944

Comment: Dear Gerard,
I have no issue retrieving data in ssms using :
`SELECT * FROM dbo.België$Cities`
on SQL SERVER 2012 via SSMS
It might be related to a collation issue between sql server and PHP.

Comment: The server is SQL SERVER 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem a lot aswell so I made it a rule to myself to always use a back-tick (`) on tablenames, which should fix your problem.

In your case

```
SELECT * FROM `België$Cities`;
```

should work.

Comment: Back tick are not used in SQL SERVER where square brackets are used.
see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573922/what-does-the-sql-standard-say-about-usage-of-backtick

Comment: Replacing square brackets with backticks does not work. I've also added to the question that the name also contains a space. Not sure if that matters.