# I am trying to insert into a table using "&" operator in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am using  `Server version: 5.6.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)`.I am trying to insert into `subodh` table using `&` operator using following query

```
insert into subodh values(&date_of_birth,&name,&age,&qualification,&id);
```

but it is showing the following error

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '&date
_of_birth,&name,&age,&qualification,&id)' at line 1
```

please help me.

Thanks

Comment: & is a special character. You can try to enter field names between back ticks. Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443050/special-characters-in-mysql-table-name

Comment: are you trying to make an insert with substitution variables like in Oracle? If yes, this is not possible in MySQL. Your application should manage the variables

Comment: if you're using a client side language (php?, Java? C#? other?) please [edit] your question tags to let us know which one. This kind of variable substitution is performed by the client side language in MySQL.